# Fill an Array with Labels

Tags: c#, arrays

I've currently got 5 labels in a Windows Form on Visual Studio and I need to populate an array with these 5 labels.

The 5 labels are named 'die1', 'die2', 'die3', 'die4', 'die5'

I figured I should be able to generate the array and then use a for loop to populate it, but the for loop is where I get stuck. This is what I have so far:

```
    Label[] labels = new Label[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
           labels[i] = new Label(die(i));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You've already got these labels, as in you dragged them onto the form and named them? `Label[] labels = new [] {die1, die2, die3, die4, die5};` will work in that case.

Comment: What do u mean by `new Label(die(i))` ?? is `die` a method which will assign a string value to the label ?

Comment: Do you want to create new Labels or read existing Labels (in the form)?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to search the collection of controls on the `Form`, and create an array from any `Label`'s whose name starts with "die":

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>()
                     .Where(label => label.Name.StartsWith("die"))
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Your solution is great, although i didn't get what he means by `new Label(die(i))` ... which sound like he is not looking for `"die"` he is assigning it.

Comment: Pedantic comment to help newbies like me! Maybe change .Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("die") to .Where(lbl => lbl.Name.StartsWith("die") ? I was totally confused by the l which I took to be a 1 for a moment! But nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
        Label[] lbl ;

        private void setupControls()
        {
            int Totallbl = 5;
            int height = 30;
            lbl = new Label[Totallbl];
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Totallbl; i++)
                {
                    lbl[i] = new Label();
                    lbl[i].Location = new Point(20, ((i + 1) * height));
                    lbl[i].Name = "lbl" + i;
                    lbl[i].Text = "LabelText";
                    lbl[i].AutoSize = true;
                    this.Controls.Add(lbl[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

> You can call back the label like this:
>
> lbl[0].Text = "Text u want to change"
>
> lbl[1].Text = "Text u want to change"
>
> ...